# Get Ajax GET request parameters on my aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am sending checkbox value from 1 ASP page to another.

I am using jQuery to make the Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http:myurl.aspx',
    type: 'GET',
    data: dataToBeDeleted,
    success: function () { alert('yay') },
    error: function () { alert("Data not deleted"); }
});
```

How do I get the values in *myurl.aspx* page? I tried with `request.QueryString["data"]` and `request.QueryString["dataToBeDeleted"]` but both gives no data.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: What is the structure of `dataToBeDeleted`?

Comment: Try to avoid using gets that take action e.g delete. Gets should retrieve data.

Comment: Hi MrChief, the dataToBeDeleted is an array that store the value of checkboxes selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the structure of your `dataToBeDeleted` parameter.

For example, if you have:

```
dataToBeDeleted = {"id1": "10", "id2": "20"};  //Object format
```

or

```
dataToBeDeleted = "id1=10&id2=20";  //String format
```

then you would read it in the server like this:

```
string id1 = Request.QueryString["id1"].ToString();
string id2 = Request.QueryString["id2"].ToString();
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Hi Edgar, thanks for the response. The dataToBeDeleted is of type array ( var dataToBeDeleted = new Array();) and I am filling this with values of checkboxes selected. I want to pass this checkbox values to another page to update the database. My dataToBeDelted will be of form value1,value2,value3,value4 etc.

Comment: $('.checkboxes_to_delete:checked').each(function (key, value) {dataToBeDeleted.push($(this).val());
});

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http:myurl.aspx?data=' + dataToBeDeleted,
            success: function () { alert('yay') },
            error: function () { alert("Data not deleted"); }
        });
```

Comment: This will just send the string 'dataToBeDeleted' as the `data` parameter.

Comment: Exactly, this will not trasfer data, you will get dataToBeDeleted String as data parameter

Comment: fixed, now try it ! that was a typo :(

Answer (score 0):

The data should be passed in key, value format as

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http:myurl.aspx',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'key1=val1&key2=val2',
            success: function () { alert('yay') },
            error: function () { alert("Data not deleted"); }
});
```